# Ubuntu 18.04 : PHP can't load dynamically any extensions

Tags: php, ubuntu

When I do php -v or php -m I get the following php warning :

"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library...", for all of my extensions installed.

- I have checked in usr/lib/php/20170718/ directory and everything's
  finely installed.
- cli/php.ini and fpm/php.ini are clean.
- I am using php7.1

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 comes with PHP 7.2 by default. How did you install your PHP 7.1?

Comment: I installed PHP-FPM 7.1 to run magento2 on nginx

Comment: I meant what deb package / apt source are you using? Or are you compiling PHP 7.1 from source code?

Comment: i used  repository ppa:ondrej/php

Comment: Have your remove all previously installed PHP packages before installing the PHP 7.1 package?

Comment: And when you do `php -v`, what does it say about the version? 7.1 or 7.2? It could be that your php 7.1 works just fine, but by installing 7.1 you messed up 7.2 that you had by default and 7.2 *could* be the version that complains and that's invoked via `php` command.

Comment: I only get a list of warning and the bottom this :

Comment: Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.16-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: finaly i did get back to php7.2, and  it resolved some problems

Comment: You were mixed using PHP 7.1 extensions and 7.2 CLI. Hence the problem. You should have removed all PHP 7.2 pacakges before adding the repository, `apt-get update` and installing PHP 7.1 with all extensions from the ppa repository.